# Help understanding whose 解釈が間違ってる

Tags: grammar, meaning, reading-comprehension

I need some help understanding whose 解釈が間違ってる in the following exchange, and also what types of situations/contexts 解釈 can be used for this type of meaning.

From the below extract it is clear that 美奈都 misunderstands big time what her elder brother 真 says. However when 真 responds to 美奈都's original misunderstanding he also misinterprets what she says(when he responds to 身も心も?). So is the protagonist's line 「いや、待て。解釈が間違ってる気がするぞ」 referring to 真, 美奈都, or both?

> 主人公「な、なんで謝るんだよ……」
>
> 真「美奈都が……妹が迷惑をかけた。すまん」
>
> 真「こいつバカだから、勝手に一人で突っ走ってさ。ほんと、おまえがいなかったら、どうなってたか……」
>
> 主人公「いいって。友達だろ」
>
> 真「友達、か……俺は、それ以上になってもいいと思ってるから」
>
> 美奈都「そ、それ以上？」
>
> 真「おまえになら、任せられるっていうかさ」
>
> 主人公「真……」
>
> 美奈都「**身も心も**……？」
>
> 真「ああ」
>
> 美奈都「あ、兄貴……そんな風に思ってたんだ……」
>
> 身も心も……？
>
> 主人公「いや、待て。**解釈が間違ってる気がするぞ**」
>
> 真「俺も今そう思った……」
>
> 真「ま、まぁなんだ。これからもよろしく頼む」
>
> 主人公「あ、ああ。もちろん。俺も、そう思ってる」
>
> 真「そっか……」

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it refers to 美奈都 or 真. She seemed to think 身も心も implied that her elder brother did not mind becoming the main character's lover and having sex with the main character. But her elder brother didn't think the phrase meant that sense.

The interpretation of 身も心も between 美奈都 and 真 is different. So 解釈が間違ってる気がするぞ refers to either. The one who wrongly interpreted 身も心も is 美奈都 from the point of view of 真, the one is 真 from the point of view of 美奈都. We don't know the main character stood in which one's position.